# ReactJS form not allowing user text input

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am creating a form in ReactJS to take in user text input and store it in a state variable. The form was working, but after reloading the webpage the form no longer allows me to input any text. This is the code for the form:

```
function UserInput({ generateResponse }) {
    const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                generateResponse(prompt, setPrompt)
            }}>
                <input className="input-prompt" type="text" value={prompt} 
                onChange={(e) => setPrompt(e.target.value)} placeholder="type here..."/>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

I tried rewriting the form's input tag code, removing the 'value' field of the input tag (though this wasn't creating any issues when it was working). I also tried restarting the browser and trying the form on other browsers, but it still doesn't work.

From what I have seen so far, this problem mainly occurs when the value of the input tag is set to something specific, so the user can't change it. But in this case I have set it to a state variable which updates on every change to the input field, so I am not sure why I can't enter input.

Comment: @FBT can you show what generateResponse() does with state and updater function because if you remove that it should work.

Comment: Try changing value to defaultValue

Comment: Could you share reproducible example?

Comment: @RegularJo I tried changing it, unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapati I tried running the form after removing the generateResponse() function from its props and just changing onSubmit() to console.log something. I am still unable to type anything into the input area.

Comment: @EBT on a few occasions I had to literally stop my app and re-start, try that. Otherwise isn't there any error at all in your console in DevTools?

Comment: @Aleksandar I tried creating a new react app and copying the code over. The same problem occurs unfortunately, it seems like there is a problem in the code. No errors appear in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The faulty CSS styling of the form made it so that clicking on the input area itself wouldn't allow any user input, but clicking on an area nowhere near the input area would instead allow for user input. This is likely due to messy arrangement of the input divs and elements on the page, not with the form code itself.